# Setup version for module 'Magento_CatalogInventoryConfigurableProduct' is not specified

Tags: magento2

Setup version for module 'Magento_CatalogInventoryConfigurableProduct' is not specified error is my issue

I installed magento 2 and when I go to my the site on my local WAMP server I get this pesky error. This is a clone from Magento 2.1.5 and I used Composer to add the Migration Tool Kit... but alas... I am stuck here. I have a little experience with Magento. Ha someone run into this error as well? How can I get out of this muddy road?

Comment: Try searching your code for "Magento_CatalogInventoryConfigurableProduct" or checking your setup_module table in the database. That module does not exist, but maybe there is an accidental typo in your code or database.

Comment: I have not modified any code... just getting a blank install set up. I do see Magento_CatalogInventoryConfigurableProduct 2.2.0 2.2.0 in the setup_module table.

Comment: Are there separate rows for Magento_CatalogInventory and Magento_ConfigurableProduct?

Comment: One row. Above is  Magento_CatalogInventory 2.2.1 2.2.1

Comment: So, this means there are not separate rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a new Magento 2.1.5 install, there should not be any **Magento_CatalogInventoryConfigurableProduct** module. If you migrated your site data from another site, then you may have encountered an error during this process. In your **setup_module** table in your database you should have a `Magento_CatalogInventory | 2.0.1 | 2.0.1` row and a `Magento_ConfigurableProduct | 2.0.0 | 2.0.0` row.

Comment: thanks for this answer... getting to know this brittle piece of "software."